# why $\mathbb E[X]=\int_{\mathbb R}x\mu_{X}(dx)$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space. I'm trying to prove $$\mathbb E[X]:=\int_\Omega Xd\mathbb P=\int_{\mathbb R}x\mu_X(dx),$$
where $X$ is a random variable and $\mu_X$ is the distribution of $X$. So, if $X=\boldsymbol 1_A$, where $A\in \mathcal F$ $$\mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_A]=\mathbb P(A)$$
and $$\int_{\mathbb R}x\mu_X(dx)=\mathbb P\{X=1\}=\mathbb P(A).$$

If $X$ is a simple function, then the equality hold. Let $X\geq 0$ and $X_n$ a sequence of simple function s.t. $X_n\nearrow X$. Using Monotone convergence,
$$\mathbb E[X]=\lim_{n\to \infty }\mathbb E[X_n]=\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_{\mathbb R}x\mu_{X_n}(dx).$$

Why $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_{\mathbb R}x\mu_{X_n}(dx)=\int_{\mathbb R}x\mu_X(dx)\ \ ?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite difficult to complete the proof using your approach. What you can do to prove this result to show that $\int f(X)dP=\int f(x)\, d\mu (x)$ for every non-negative measurable function $f: \mathbb  R \to \mathbb R$. [ When $f$ is not non-negative the question of existence of the integrals on the two sides has to be taken in to account].  Now. if $f$ is a simple function the equation follow easily from the definition $\mu (A)=P(X^{-1}(A))$. If $(f_n)$ is a sequence of simple functions increasing to $f$ we can write the equation for each $f_n$ and take the limit. Monotone Convergence Theorem is now very easy to apply.

Comment: I see, nice trick, thank you :) Just to know, it's not possible that $\lim_{n\to \infty }\int x\mu_{X_n}(dx)=\int_{\mathbb R}x\mu(dx)$ ?

Comment: You have to know $\mu_{X_n}$ is related to $\mu_X$. The sequence converges weakly but the identity function $f(x)=x$ is not a bounded continuous function . So the proof becomes very complicated.  The question itself is a basic question about mean of a random variable and it doesn't make sense to go into weak convergence of measures to prove this.